# How can I tell which driver Xorg is using for my video card?

Tags: driver, intel, xorg

I downloaded and compiled the latest intel video drivers as mine seems to have issues, I installed with prefix as /usr/local. Then I added the appropriate

```
Section "Device"
  Identifier "devname"
  Driver "intel"
EndSection
```

How can I tell if it's using my new compiled driver or something that comes with my distro? What Xorg command displays which library files or some other recognisable info as to how I can determine it's using the new driver (other than waiting for the screen to corrupt again).

Comment: Not so sure this is going to help, but I remember that a while ago redirecting the error stream of the X server to a file ($ X 2>out.txt) helped me to debug some issues with Xorg.

Comment: This is question for serverfault.com and not for stackoverflow.com

Comment: Is there a duplicate of this on https://superuser.com or any of the other stackexchange sites?  If so, this off-topic sysadmin question should pretty definitely be deleted.

Answer (score -2):

Just look at the Xorg log file it says in there.

Comment: Well, X log often shows loading more than one video drivers, so it is unclear from the log.